# Is there a name for this subspace: the orthogonal complement of kernel of a matrix ??

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In the co-domain side: we have the range (or the image) and it's orthogonal complement is called the cokernel.

In the pre-domain side: we have the kernel, but what would you call its orthogonal complement?

EDIT: my question stemmed from this
[image]

Comment: That's not what I call the cokernel.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I learnt that from here:
https://youtu.be/SFHFugs21qY?t=2473

Comment: The orthogonal complement (when it exists) and the cokernel are closely related (in fact, they are usually isomorphic), but they are not the same, conventionally. One might simplify this in an introductory lecture, or a lecture in a subject that's not really theory heavy, but I think that's wrong.

Comment: @Arthur I believe you mean that the orthogonal complement of the kernel is isomorphic to the *range*. Cokernel is not usually isomorphic to them.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე kernel only exists if the matrix is wide, and cokernel only exists if its tall. As such, only one of them is nontrivial for a given matrix. Is that what you mean by 'usually' ?

Comment: @JohnDeterious Maybe we mean different things. For me, kernel of $A$ is $\{v\mid Av=0\}$ and exists always. Cokernel is the quotient of the codomain by the image and also exists always. Both kernel or cokernel might be zero space but they always exist. Kernel is guaranteed to be nonzero if the matrix is wide but might be nonzero even if it is not - for example kernel of the zero matrix is always the whole domain regardless of the shape of the matrix. Similarly cokernel is guaranteed to be nonzero if the matrix is tall but can be nonzero even if it is not.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I meant the orthogonal complement of the range is usually isomorphic to the cokernel. It was building off of Lord Shark's previous comment, but I agree it was unclear. And I said usually not because I had any particular counterexample in mind, but because I know that subtleties appear in infinite dimensions, and I didn't want to have to look into whether that applied here. Also, @ John Deterious, kernels and cokernels _always_ exist, regardless of the shape of the matrix, but some times they are just the zero space.

Comment: @Arthur I see. Yes, in the finite-dimensional case the orthogonal complement of the range is *always* isomorphic to the cokernel.

Comment: The row space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its kernel (null space).

Comment: @amd Right. In fact you may well *define* the null space as the orthogonal complement of the row space.